# c++ use tuple as parameter pack in template

Tags: c++, templates

I am using `boost::callable_traits::args_t` to get std::tuple of arguments types from method. Is it possible to use that tuple as parameter pack?

```
void doJob(int i) {
  std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
template<auto F>
void magic(boost::callable_traits::args_t<F> ...args) { // here is the magic
  F(args...)
}
magic<doJob>(1);
```

This is something I want to implement. I want to make this without using variadic templates.

Comment: You cannot have a parameter pack (expansion) without a variadic template. Why is not using one a requirement?

Comment: You want something that looks and behaves like a variadic template pack, but without using one??

Comment: @user10605163, fixed

Comment: @super, exactly

Comment: It is impossible to do what you want without a variadic template, but with one it can be done, so that `magic<doJob>(1);` works as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use C++17 you can use [`std::apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) to call the function.  `std::apply` takes a callable and a tuple and calls the callable with the unpacked tuple as the function arguments.  That would make `magic` look like

```
template<auto F>
void magic(boost::callable_traits::args_t<F> args) { // here is the magic
  std::apply(F, args);
}
```

Comment: this is not what I want. So I want to do this -  "template<auto F, typename ARGS...> void magic(ARGS ...args)" but without variardic template.

Comment: @crashtua I see.  You cant get a parameter pack without a variadic template parameter.